# Django - extended User profile, object does not exist, how to create a blank record?

Tags: python, django

ive created a user profile class as per below, if the user clicks on the my account page and they dont have a record i get the below error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile
User has no userprofile.
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
User has no userprofile.
```

and this is the error line

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
```

so i thought i need to put a try around that section? but im not sure how to create a record as the exception?

Thanks

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    mpls_m_subscriptions = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="MPLS Maintenance Subscription",choices=settings.SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE,blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('home:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    return render(request, 'home/profile.html', {
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend doing the following two things:

1. Create a Data migration that creates a blank user profile for all existing users [Django Migrations Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)
2. Create a post_save signal handler for User to automatically create a profile object when a new user is created [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/)

Comment: Thanks! Code for this solution: https://maketips.net/tip/193/create-user-profiles-in-django-if-they-does-not-exist (`post_save` + data migration )

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first user exists or not

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.userprofile is None:
            user_profile = UserProfile(user=request.user)
            user_profile.save
        ...
```

Comment: i got the same error at "if request.user.userprofile: # check user not none" error: " 
User has no userprofile."

Comment: the user does exist, they just dont have a userprofile, user profile is an extended model

Comment: if user exist then create a userprofile for that user

Comment: im getting the error "user has no userprofile" for the check if request.user.userprofile. which doesnt make sense to me, becuase thats the check...

Comment: `userprofile = UserProfile(user=request.user)  userprofile.save()` ? something like this. I dont understand the relationship.