# django+heroku error in createsuperuser "psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation ”users_profile“ does not exist"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

i am new to django,there is no problem in local system for this , makemigrations,migrate and createsuperuser everything works fine in local system.but when i am trying to deploy in heroku with postgresql makemigrations and migrate ran fine, problem is when i am trying to createsuperuser, it is giving me an error.

```
(djangoenv) E:\youngminds>heroku run bash
Running bash on ? youngminds... up, run.8229 (Free)
~ $ python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'u21088'): johnson
Email address: johnson@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_profile" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "users_profile" ("user_id", "image", "descriptio...
                    ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/_
_init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/b
ase.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mana
gement/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/b
ase.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mana
gement/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user
_data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mode
ls.py", line 161, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mode
ls.py", line 144, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base
_user.py", line 73, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 769, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatch
er.py", line 178, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatch
er.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)


  File "/app/users/signals.py", line 9, in create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance) ####problem in this line

  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager
.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.p
y", line 417, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager
.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.p
y", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/com
piler.py", line 1281, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", lin
e 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils
.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_profile" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "users_profile" ("user_id", "image", "descriptio...
```

i have no table named users_profile ,than why is this giving me this error only in createsuperuser command , there were no problems in makemigrations and migrate command.

i can see there is problem in signals.py file from error but dont know how to what is causing this error and how to solve it.

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        pass

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

migrations command in heroku bash.

```
(djangoenv) E:\youngminds>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'blog':
  blog\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model about_page_details
    - Create model carousel_images_messages
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Comment
    - Create model No_Of_Views
    - Create model Post
    - Add field post to comment
    - Add field reply to comment
    - Add field user to comment
    - Add field category to carousel_images_messages
Migrations for 'users':
  users\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Profile

(youngmindsenv) E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions, social_django
, users
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

signals.py file is in same level as models.py and urls.py

i have gone through almost every answers regarding this but none have same kind of error like this.

Please help me on this, any extra informations required for this , i will update.

Thanks in advance

**Update**

---

the problem is solved , what i did to solve it is

1) deleted my table of production as i didn't have any data's in there.

as suggested by chris in the comment

2) ran makemigrations command locally
3) ran migrate command directly in heroku bash without running makemigrations

doing this the problem got solved !

Hopefully this will help someone in future ! Thanks everyone who gave time to comment on this

Comment: You do have a Profile model, so you should have a users_profile table. Did you add "users" to INSTALLED_APPS? Have migrations been created for that app?

Comment: @DanielRoseman ya i have added users.apps.UsersConfig  in installed app. ya i have seen the migrations folder there is some files.what is wrong with my signals.py file?

Comment: The problem isn't with your signal. As I said, it seems that the table has not been created by your migrations; either the migrations were not created for the users app, or have not been run for some reason.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have added makemigrations and migrate command in heroku bash and its result , is there any problem in this?

Comment: But that is only locally. You need to add those migration files to git, deploy them to Heroku, and then run migrate there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman same thing happens in heroku as well but there createsuperuser gives the above error , but in local system createsuperuser works fine

Comment: What do you mean, the same thing? As I said, you need to make migrations locally, add them to git, deploy to Heroku, then run migrate there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry i was unclear on that, i have done makemigrations locally and added it on git and than in heroku but the problem still persists.dont i have to use makemigrations on heroku ? should i use migrate directly in heroku without makemigrations

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041162/8363401) out I hope it may help somehow because the problem that you are mentioning should not happen unless or until something is changing manually.

Comment: "dont i have to use makemigrations on heroku ?"—no. This creates migration files, which you've done locally. By the time your code is deployed there should be no model changes that would result in new migrations. "should i use migrate directly in heroku without makemigrations"—yes, to apply the migrations defined in the migration files you generated locally to your production database.

Comment: @Chris thank you for your help ! what i did to solve this, i deleted my tables from database and did makemigrations in local and then used directly migrate in heroku and problem got solved ! thanks again

Comment: How did you delete your table of production?